# jdoc:include inside an <input type="button"?

Tags: html, css, joomla

I'm working on an Website and I have a problem.
I have a `<input type="button"...` and if I put the `<jdoc:include..../>` Tag inside the "value" statement like this:

`<input type="button" value="<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-top" style="xhtml"/>">`

it doesn't work, because the "" are false.

So my question: how can I do it right?

Thanks!

Comment: Escape the `"` or try `value='<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-top" style="xhtml"/>'`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney already tried, does not work too.

Comment: The escape suggested by Darren Sweeney works for me. Where you put it? It doesn't work in some components because the `jdoc:include` directive doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution 1 year and 10 months later.
As @Darren Sweeney already mentioned in the comments, I had to escape the code like this:

`<input type="button" value="<jdoc:include type='modules' name='left-top' style='xhtml'/>">`